# Mapbox How to conduct a if else statement expression

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am currently working on a function where the users can click anywhere within a polygon and a popup window shows up. However, I also wrote a function that once the users click on certain locations, a popup window displaying the information about those locations also shows up. So I ended up having two popup windows when I click on certain locations, how can I possibly change that?

JS Code for clicking anywhere within the polygon to show popup:

```
    map.on('click', 'CHOP Zone Transparent', (e) => {
        new mapboxgl.Popup().setLngLat(e.lngLat).setHTML(`
                                      <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Comment</button>`).addTo(map);
    });
```

JS code for clicking on certain locations' icons to show popup:

```
// Allow user to comment and comment once click on icons
for (const feature of stores.features) {
    // create a HTML element for each feature
    const el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'store';
    // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates).setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
        offset: 25
    }).setHTML(`
                                      <h2>${feature.properties.title}</h2>
                                      <p>${feature.properties.description}</p>
                                      <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Comment</button>`)).addTo(map);
}
```

Issue:

[Two Popup Windows Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3W6s.png)

How do I use some sort of if/else statement or other expressions to resolve this problem?

Comment: I think you should look into event bubbling and then probably use `e.stopPropagation()` somewhere in your code, but what you provided is not detailed or complete enough